# How to have different postfix options based upon destination email address

Tags: postfix, email-server

I need to configure postfix in such a way that the options used vary dependent upon the destination email address.  For example, I might have destinations such as **user@foo.com**, **user@bar.com**, **user@baz.bar.com**, etc.  I would like to have different configuration options (and forwarding destinations) for each.

Is this possible?  Any suggestions as to how to realize this?

Thanks

Comment: Start by explaining what you want to do and what you have so far. It depends on *which* options you need to change. Fine-tuning outgoing transports? Easy. Complex conditional forwarding? Might as well run entirely separate relays.